# SQL SUM or COUNT with CASE - which would be more efficient

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, count, sum, case

If I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 database table with a primary key of `subject_id` (`INT`) AND `category_id` (`INT`) and a column that is a bit mask (yes, horror of horrors a bit mask!, but it is what it is and bit masks do not scare me, as well as other columns which have been omitted for clarity)...

Given the two queries below, which would be more efficient? I tried using the client statistics and execution plan output, but the stats seem to vary each time I run the queries and does not point to a clear winner per se.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN ( category_id = 1 AND ( bit_mask & 4 ) = 4 ) THEN 1
                 WHEN ( category_id = 2 AND ( bit_mask & 8 ) = 8 ) THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 END )
FROM data_tbl
WHERE subject_id = 12;
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM data_tbl
 WHERE subject_id = 12
   AND 1 = ( CASE WHEN ( category_id = 1 AND ( bit_mask & 4 ) = 4 ) THEN 1
                  WHEN ( category_id = 2 AND ( bit_mask & 8 ) = 8 ) THEN 1
                  ELSE 0 END );
```

If some SQL guru can take a look and instantly tell which query is more efficient (or are they the same?) please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just run those two queries in Mgmt Studio yourself and compare! You can use the actual execution plan and the execution statistics to see how the two are performing compared to one another ....

Comment: I did, but as I mentioned in the original post, the stats seem to vary each time (not pointing to a clear winner); probably something I am doing wrong before running the test.

Answer (score 0):

Neither. This should out-perform both:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM data_tbl
WHERE subject_id = 12
AND (
  (category_id = 1 AND ( bit_mask & 4 ) = 4 ) 
  OR 
  (category_id = 2 AND ( bit_mask & 8 ) = 8 )
)
```

The reason is this query gives the optimizer a better chance to process the logic using indexes or whatever. Your queries bury the counting logic in calculations out of reach of the optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it depends, mainly on cardinality and selectivity. My guess is that the second one has better chance to be faster. Check the execution plans against your real data to be sure.

However, the fastest variant would probably be this one:

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN ( category_id = 1 AND ( bit_mask & 4 ) = 4 ) THEN 1
                 WHEN ( category_id = 2 AND ( bit_mask & 8 ) = 8 ) THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 END )
FROM data_tbl
WHERE subject_id = 12
AND category_id in (1, 2);
```

Again, it's just a guess, and it might easily be outperformed by an UNION ALL (one SELECT for each category_id).

Answer (score 0):

OK - Thanks for the replies everyone - I tested the suggestions supplied, below are the results that the query analyzer reports:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN ( category_id = 1 AND ( bit_mask & 4 ) = 4 ) THEN 1
                 WHEN ( category_id = 2 AND ( bit_mask & 8 ) = 8 ) THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 END )
 FROM data_tbl
WHERE subject_id = 12
  AND category_id in ( 1, 2);
```

Average "Total Execution Time" after 10 trials: 10.8

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM data_tbl
WHERE subject_id = 12
  AND ( ( category_id = 1 AND ( bit_mask & 4 ) = 4 ) OR 
        ( category_id = 2 AND ( bit_mask & 8 ) = 8 ) );
```

Average "Total Execution Time" after 10 trials: 11.6

The strange thing is the execution plan looks identical in both cases.  So its looking like Query 1 is going to be the one to go with.